# Cannot integrate paypal into my ionic application

Tags: ios, paypal, ionic-framework

Need help with `papypal` integration in ionic application. I've tried `cordova-paypal` plugin also but it doesn't work for me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could just use the APIs to make calls directly to PayPal from your app.  Need a lot more detail to be able to point you in the right direction, though.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewAngell. i am trying to integrate cordova-paypal plugin in the app but its not working. i am just searching for another way to integrate paypal. Will i need to download sdk in my ionic project?

Comment: Probably, but it just depends.  Are you wanting to do everything in Javascript?  Are you wanting to build PHP services that the Javascript would talk to?  Need more details.  Question is too broad.

Comment: Let me explain you. I am working on an ionic application which needs  payment gateway integration. Its my first application in ionic so i am getting  confused in how to integrate payment gateway and process it. I am using php rest webservices in the application, so i can handle the php services. Cordova paypal plugin is not working in the application and i didnt find any other method that works. Hope you understand.